# How to check the status parameter in Laravel 5.2 routing using the where keywords?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Following is the routing code I am using in my script:-

```
Route::any('/set-status/{id}/{status}', [ 'as'=>'admin_service_category_set_status', 
                                                'uses'=>'Admin\ServiceCategoryController@set_status'])
                    ->where(array('id'=> '[0-9]+', 'status' => '[a-z]+');
```

Here, the script checks whether the 'status' contains alphabets or not. I want it to check whether status is either 'activate' or 'deactivate'. 
How can I do  that?

Answer (score 1):

You just need set: `'status' => 'activate|deactivate'`

```
 Route::any('/set-status/{id}/{status}', [ 
'as'=>'admin_service_category_set_status', 
'uses'=>'Admin\ServiceCategoryController@set_status'])-
>where(array('id'=> '[0-9]+', 'status' => 'activate|deactivate'));
```